# Position my weapon following a bone

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I'm trying to display a weapon following a bone animated with XNAnimation.
My weapon follows the bone, but I need to apply an offset, because the weapon is not well positionned on the hand, I have a screenprint :

[image]

In fact, the Machete is very far away... I draw it thanks to this matrix :

```
        public Matrix GetBoneMatrix(string boneName, float scale)
    {
        int index = skinnedModel.Model.Bones[boneName].Index;

        Matrix boneLocal = animationController.SkinnedBoneTransforms[index];

        boneLocal =     Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0f))
                        * Matrix.CreateScale(scale)
                        * Matrix.Invert(skinnedModel.SkeletonBones[index].InverseBindPoseTransform)
                        * animationController.SkinnedBoneTransforms[index]
                        * _rotation 
                        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(_position);

        return boneLocal;
    }
```

I use this function in my draw function :

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in weap.GetModel(weap._selectedWeapon).Meshes) 
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)  
            {
                // Draw the weapon thanks to bones position
                effect.World = _handAnimation.GetBoneMatrix("hand_R", 0.02f);

                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
```

I did not find how to well position the weapon...
If you have any idea :)

Thank you for the answer and I apologize for my english

Comment: Nice render ! Did you export your model with centered origin ? Otherwise it would have an offset each time from initial position you rendered it

Comment: Thank you :D I am on it since septemer. I exported from blender in position O - O - O Normaly, I would not have to create an offset but I did it :) and it works perfectly, thank you a lot :D